# Jquery fading slideshow if statement

Tags: jquery, slideshow

HI I need to create a if statement for my slide show, if there is only one image I don't want the slideshow to be active;

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

    // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});

</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="image1.jpg"  class="active" />
```

JS is not really my strong suit, any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `domready` function to this:

```
$(function() {
    if ($("#slideshow img").length > 1) {
      setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    }
});
```